# Name attribute on ASP.NET MVC action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have this action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(Test test) 
{
    ...
}
```

With this class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string txtTest { get; set; }
}
```

An html form has a text field named *txtTest*, and I can successfully call into my action above. What property name would allow me to do this:

```
public class Test
{
    [SomeAttribute(Name = "txtTest")]
    public string MyTest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate some more?

Comment: Currently I am forced to match the name of my C# class's variable with the form field's name. I cannot change the name of the form field.

Comment: If you change the name of the form field, it will not be mapped back correctly to your class.  If you want to do custom fields, you'll also have to write a custom ModelBinder.  This SMELLS of an [XY Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858), because you have some solution but you aren't telling us what problem it is solving.

Comment: Another way to say my question is "What attribute on a class property will allow me to name that property as I see fit while still allowing MVC to correctly create instances of those classes in a controller action". I don't believe that this is an XY question.

Comment: @user961969. Didn't my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

Use ViewModel, don't use classes which are being used for something else.
Create ViewModel, for this specific View only.

**one** of the benefits is you don't need to change the names of properties the existing classes have.

You can use [`automapper`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) which is highly used in MVC  applications to map from the ViewModel to the Entity.

A good reading resource can be [found here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding you - I am not calling View() at all. I am simply trying to receive form data.

Comment: @user961969, so get that data with the viewmodel in the POST action. you can use AutoMapper to map from the DTO to the CTO.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Display DataAnnotation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure it has anything to do with his question.

Comment: I tried this to no avail: [DisplayAttribute(Name = "txtTest")]
  public string MyTest { get; set; }

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations ?

Comment: Yes.The code compiled correctly, but the value from the form field was not present in the C# object.

Comment: Can you post the internals of your action and also your view code thanks.

Comment: @gdoron, I agree that clarification would definitely help